# What IS the energy density of vacuum space (or spacetime)?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, energy, spacetime, vacuum, cosmological-constant

The question, even if similar to other questions here, pretends to clarify a subtle question: the identity of vacuum energy (or energy-density being more precise).

Should we be confident in the measured cosmological constant being the SAME vacuum energy density that the one much bigger that are provide in Quantum Field Theory calculations (with some cut-off) or are we indeed facing two different entities?